# Create a Splunk alert from a log file when a file with name hello.imp is below 10 bytes

Tags: splunk, splunk-query, splunk-formula, splunk-calculation, splunk-dashboard

I'm trying to write a Splunk query where it searches for a file called hello.imp from a log file and returns with a output if the file size is below 10 bytes. I have the index and log location but unable to find the exact query. Please help me out in a writing a query and creating an alert out of it.

Comment: Why would a filename be in a logfile?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the size of a source file by adding up the sizes of each event within that file.  Like this:

```
index=foo source=bar
| eval size=len(_raw)
| stats sum(size) as TotalSize
```

Comment: I'd *think* `_raw` would be bigger than 10 bytes just due to event overhead. Can't recall ever seeing an event *less* than ~30 bytes, personally

Comment: Good point,  I suppose it depends on the sourcetype's DATETIME_CONFIG setting.  It may be necessary to subtract the timestamp from the size of each event.